# Cannot call a class as a function in react-native and run's using expo

Tags: react-native, expo

I am working in a react-native project using expo there is an error I have shared the link, please share an error-free code. I will share my code in the description

link for my exact error

[image]

App.js

```
 import React from 'react';
    import MovieList from './components/list';
    import  Detail from './components/detail';
    
    
    import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
    import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
    
    const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
      MovieList: {screen: MovieList},
      Detail: {screen: Detail},
    
    })
    
    const App = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
    
    export default App();
```

detail.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text} from 'react-native';
 
 export default class Detail extends React.Component {
 
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Details page here</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center"
  },
  item: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 10,
    height: 50,
    backgroundColor: '#282C35'
  },
  itemText: {
color: '#fff',
fontSize: 24
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`export default App();` should be `export default App;` instead. The error is telling you that `App` is not a function, so you need to remove the parentheses.